# How to merge values from similar rows in an array to rows containing both data in php

Tags: php

I have a phone book array I get from a database, where everyone appears once with their stationary phone number and a second with their mobile number.

I need to make this an array where everyone has only one line, with their phone number and mobile number

```
//My array
$data = array(
array('name'=>'robert','family'=>'bridgstone','home'=>'0258101234'),
array('name'=>'robert','family'=>'bridgstone','phone'=>'07258101235'),
array('name'=>'dan','family'=>'swartz','home'=>'098101244'),
array('name'=>'ben','family'=>'wais','home'=>'0447256155778'),
array('name'=>'ben','family'=>'wais','phone'=>'04472861558878'),
);

  //The result that should come out
    $data = array(
array('name'=>'robert','family'=>'bridgstone','home'=>'0258101234','phone'=>'07258101235'),
array('name'=>'dan','family'=>'swartz','home'=>'098101244','phone'=>''),
array('name'=>'ben','family'=>'wais','home'=>'0447256155778','phone'=>'04472861558878')
);
```

Comment: You have shown the data your using and want, but have not shown any coding attempt to solve this yourself yet.

Comment: Start by looping though the array and finding common names and then pushing both object data to one object then push that to a new array.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a coding service.  [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way:

1. first I would **generate a unique key that identify the row** (in your case the name and the family, for example).
2. then check **if a element with the same key exist, if it already exist merge the two component**.
3. **Optional** if you only want an array of values **transform the result with array_value function**.

```php
$dataArray = array(
    array('name'=>'robert','family'=>'bridgstone','home'=>'0258101234'),
    array('name'=>'robert','family'=>'bridgstone','phone'=>'07258101235'),
    array('name'=>'dan','family'=>'swartz','home'=>'098101244'),
    array('name'=>'ben','family'=>'wais','home'=>'0447256155778'),
    array('name'=>'ben','family'=>'wais','phone'=>'04472861558878'),
);


$result = [];

foreach($dataArray as $data){
    //Just in case that the name or the family is not assigned (operator ??)
    $key = ($data['name']??'').'-'.($data['family']??'');
    $result[$key] = array_merge($result[$key]??[],$data);
}

//Optional, get only the array values

$result = array_values($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did so

```
$data = array(
array('name'=>'robert','family'=>'bridgstone','home'=>'0258101234'),
array('name'=>'robert','family'=>'bridgstone','phone'=>'07258101235'),
array('name'=>'dan','family'=>'swartz','home'=>'098101244'),
array('name'=>'ben','family'=>'wais','home'=>'0447256155778'),
array('name'=>'ben','family'=>'wais','phone'=>'04472861558878'),
);    
count($data) < 2 ? exit(): $data;
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
$array_unique[$i] = $data[$i]["name"];
$array_unique[$i] = $data[$i]["family"];
}
$array_unique = array_unique($array_unique);
if(count($array_unique) == 1){
$last_array[0]=$array_unique[0];
$last_array[0]["phone"]=$array_unique[0]["phone"];
}
else{
$array_uniqueKeys = array_keys($array_unique);

for($i = 0;$i < count($array_unique);$i++){
    $firstIndex = $i + 1;
    $firstIndex == count($array_unique) ? $nextKey = count($data) : $nextKey = $array_uniqueKeys[$firstIndex];
    $paar = $nextKey - $array_uniqueKeys[$i];

    $dataslice = array();
            $i3=0;
            for($i2 = $array_uniqueKeys[$i];$i2 < ($array_uniqueKeys[$i]+$paar);$i2++){

                if(in_array($i2,$array_uniqueKeys)){
                    $last_array[$i]=$data[$i2];
                }
                else{
                    $last_array[$i]["phone"]=$data[$i2]["phone"];
                }
                $i3++;
            }
}
}
print_r($last_array);
```